# Angular Partial View

Tags: css, angular, html

I am working on a very long form in angular. I would like to know if I can break it up into many different views and reference each of them in the main view.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" id="part1">
      <div class="col-md-12">First Section</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="part2">
      <div class="col-md-12">Second Section</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row" id="part3">
      <div class="col-md-12">Third Section</div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>

Since my file is too long, is there a way using angular to have each section in a separate file and reference each of them in the main file? For example:


 <div class="container>
    "import section 1"
    "import section 2"
    "import section 3"
 </div>

Thanks.
```

Comment: you can use `ngIf` to only show selected dics

Comment: You can also use multiple children components and use them here. And for the data, you can use a service or something to have all the data in the same place there

Comment: `[ngSwitch]` is a better option for your case I guess

Comment: I only want to reduce the size of the file, the number of line of codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your partial views (Component);

Using Angular CLI go to `powershell / comand line / etc`;

**Step1**

```
ng g c import-section-1
ng g c import-section-2
ng g c import-section-3
```

Will create you 3 folders under `app` folder (that means you'll have 3 new component);

**Step2**

Edit your component as you need and than reference the component that you need;

```
 <div class="container>
    <app-import-section-1></app-import-section-1>
    <app-import-section-2></app-import-section-2>
    <app-import-section-3></app-import-section-3>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks ShadowFoOrm, I do not want new components they are all from the same component. How do I do that?

Comment: You asked to have separate file... This is how you do it. Of course you don't need the `.scss/.css` file not even the `.spec.ts` file. You can remove the .html file as well if you want to use only `.ts file`. but if you do that your html needs to be in the `ts` file. instead of `templateUrl` you will have `template: `your html content,

Comment: Yes separate files, but I am submitting the form at once. So I only want a single component for all the sections of the view.

Comment: @DavidSagang were you able to find a solution to your question? I assume splitting the form into three components will require passing the data from child to parent and you wanted to avoid this scenario. I actually face the same challenge.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the technique presented by @shadowFoOrm and then split the form up into tabs like shown below:

[image]

You can find the code for this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing/tree/master/APM-Final

Comment: Yes. Very little (practically nothing) has changed with forms or routing since this code was written. The only that that has changed a bit is the RxJS and the Http.